# Unable to auto-deploy bundle to Karaf

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, autodeploy

I am developing an OSGI-based application, which deploys to Karaf container. Karaf has an auto-deployment feature, whereby copying a bundle to its karaf/deploy directory should automatically deploy that bundle into the container. More often than not, however, I am getting errors similar to the one below when I copy bundles into the deploy directory:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique: legacy-services-impl:8.0.0.ALPHA-SPRINT9-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.createRevision(BundleImpl.java:1225)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.<init>(BundleImpl.java:95)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2979)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:165)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.installOrUpdateBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1030)[6:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.3.11.fuse-71-047]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.install(DirectoryWatcher.java:944)[6:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.3.11.fuse-71-047]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.install(DirectoryWatcher.java:857)[6:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.3.11.fuse-71-047]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:483)[6:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.3.11.fuse-71-047]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:291)[6:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.3.11.fuse-71-047]
```

Instead of redeploying an already deployed bundle, the container tells me that I am trying to deploy a duplicate bundle.

The Karaf indeed has that bundle deployed, but why wouldn't it redeploy the bundle? What is causing this behavior? How to avoid such errors on auto-deploy?

Thank you,

Michael

Comment: which version are you using? And btw. asking this on the users-list usually gives you a much faster and better feedback :-)

Comment: Achim, this is Karaf bundled with Fuse (2.3.0.fuse-71-047). How do I access users-list?

Comment: The Karaf user list is available at: http://karaf.apache.org/index/community/mailing-lists.html

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your bundle does not stop correctly. That may be the reason why karaf thinks it is still there. Do you have some code in your activator that is executed when stopping? Perhaps you are also running some threads. You should make sure the stop method of your activator works and cleanly closes all resources and stops all threads of your bundle.